# How to add a Sandbox account along with a regular AppleId?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, sandbox, storekit

If I want to test an App using a Sandbox account, I need to sign out from my Apple ID and sign in with the Sandbox one, so I need to keep going back and fourth between accounts.

My colleague, managed to have them both at the same time under Settings > App Store (See screenshot), but he doesn't know how he did it! And I can't find anything on this regard.

I don't have this option on my device!

[image]

Comment: It's exactly where your screen shot shows it — in Settings, under App Store. You've given the answer so what's the question?

Comment: @matt I don't have the option on my device :(

Comment: Maybe because you keep switching to the sandbox account, which is wrong. Stay in your real account and run your app from Xcode.

Comment: Also you might have to make a new sandbox account, because you have messed this one up by signing into it, a thing you should never do.

Comment: @matt I need to use sandbox to I can test AppPay! I am not sure who switching is wrong? Also, I believe this has nothing to do with the App and Xcode, I just want to have both a regular Apple Id and a Sandbox Apple Id. The account is working just fine btw

Comment: Easy there, I'm just trying to help you make that section of the App Store appear on your phone.

Comment: And I appreciate your help , apologies if something offended you.

Comment: What happens when a sandbox account is logged in to? What gets messed up?

Comment: @delano nothings happens, it's just I need to have both, regular and sandbox account at the same time. My colleague did it, and we don't know how. Switching between your Apple ID and Sandbox for testing is a lot